# Wrong count result

Tags: sql-server, count

I have 2 tables in sql server:
Employee (Job Title, Hire Date)

- Person (FirstName, LastName)
  And I need to return the  E.JobTitle, E.HireDate,P.FirstName ,P.LastName along with the how many employees have the same job title.

so I used this query:

```sql
SELECT E.JobTitle,
       E.HireDate,
       P.FirstName,
       P.LastName,
       COUNT(E.JobTitle)
FROM AdventureWorks2019.HumanResources.Employee E
     JOIN AdventureWorks2019.Person.Person P ON E.BusinessEntityID = P.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY E.JobTitle,
         E.HireDate,
         P.FirstName,
         P.LastName;
```

the problem is that the query returns 1 per the count, while I'd expect to get per each row the count of the num employees with that job title.
my question is how can I get the correct count?

Comment: You're grouping on the employee's name, so you are going to get 1 row per employee name, not Job Title. Seems like you should be removing the names and hire date from the query (in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`).

Comment: I can't remove the other fields from the select because they're required there

Comment: Then use a windowed aggregate instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned by @Larnu in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441347/wrong-count-result/68452777#comment120956703_68441347), your issue is that you're grouping by `LastName` also, so you are going to get a count of 1 per `LastName`.

**You need a windowed count with `OVER`, not an aggregated one with `GROUP BY`**

No extra joins or grouping needed.

```sql
SELECT E.JobTitle,
       E.HireDate,
       P.FirstName,
       P.LastName,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY E.JobTitle)
FROM AdventureWorks2019.HumanResources.Employee E
     JOIN AdventureWorks2019.Person.Person P ON E.BusinessEntityID = P.BusinessEntityID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should count the number of employee for each job title first in a subquery or cte.

```
SELECT
        JobTitle,
        COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM HumanResources.Employee
    GROUP BY JobTitle
```

Then you can join the subquery or the cte with your original query.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
            JobTitle,
            COUNT(*) AS Count
        FROM HumanResources.Employee
        GROUP BY JobTitle
)
SELECT
    E.JobTitle,
    E.HireDate,
    P.FirstName,
    P.LastName,
    cte.Count
    FROM
        HumanResources.Employee E
        INNER JOIN Person.Person P ON P.BusinessEntityID = E.BusinessEntityID
        INNER JOIN cte on cte.JobTitle = E.JobTitle
    ORDER BY
        E.JobTitle,
        P.LastName,
        P.FirstName
;
```